# Where is the 14th system in the Agrippina subsector?

Tags: battlefleet-gothic-armada-2

I am around round 67 and about to conquer Bellis Corona and investigate "Necron turncoat" in Reznor system in Chinchare. Yet, even after conquering Agrippina subsector (you can see that all the 13 dots are Imperial Navy Blue), the map keeps saying that I am missing one (conquered 13/14)

[image]

Where is the 14th system? I've unlocked and conquered Arilla Bay, previously occupied by Eldar Corsairs. Is it hidden and will be visible later or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It unlocks near the end of the campaign (for imperium at least). After the third to last primary mission, a side mission opens up and reveals the last system.

minor spoiler, the primary mission in question and some further details:

> the one where you have to defeat the four chosen of Abaddon. I think it's tied to the one in the Belial sector, but as that was the last one I defeated, it may also be completing the entire mission. However defeating the others also always unlocked a new side mission, some of which revealed previously hidden systems.

You'll find a few more such systems, which unlock after completing a primary mission later in the campaign.

Comment: Just to confirm: this particular system opens up (in the Empire campaign) after defeating the last of the Chosen of Abaddon. It is tied to a special mission "Road to Holy Terra".... which gives you an AMAZING reward.